# Volume buttons on Surface Pro 2 not working in Ubuntu 17

Tags: volume-control, media-buttons

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10, but also tried the past Ubuntu 17 version. The side volume buttons on the Surface pro 2 do nothing when pressed. However, they work on LM 18.2, and on past Ubuntu version including 16.04. Any suggestions? How can I go about to provide more details, or any sort of logs to have this problem fixed.

After a few days I still cannot figure it out.